# Incorrect Recursive approach to finding combinations of coins to produce given change

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I was recently doing a project euler problem (namely #31) which was basically finding out how many ways we can sum to 200 using elements of the set {1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200}.

The idea that I used was this: the number of ways to sum to N is equal to

> (the number of ways to sum N-k) * (number of ways to sum k), summed over all possible values of k.

I realized that this approach is WRONG, namely due to the fact that it creates several several duplicate counts. I have tried to adjust the formula to avoid duplicates, but to no avail. I am seeking the wisdom of stack overflowers regarding:

1. whether my recursive approach is concerned with the *correct* subproblem to solve
2. If there exists one, what would be an effective way to eliminate duplicates
3. how should we approach recursive problems such that we are concerned with the correct subproblem? what are some indicators that we've chosen a correct (or incorrect) subproblem?

Comment: Try looking at the set of numbers you have, instead of the value you need to get to. `200` can be used once - in exactly one way. Now look at the set without `200`. What can you see from there?

Comment: Look for coin change problem

Comment: There's a nice explanation here: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change

Answer (score 5):

When trying to avoid duplicate permutations, a straightforward strategy that works in most cases is to only create rising or falling sequences.

In your example, if you pick a value and then recurse with the whole set, you will get duplicate sequences like `50,50,100` and `50,100,50` and `100,50,50`. However, if you recurse with the rule that the next value should be equal to or smaller than the currently selected value, out of those three you will only get the sequence `100,50,50`.

So an algorithm that counts only unique combinations would be e.g.:

```
function uniqueCombinations(set, target, previous) {
    for all values in set not greater than previous {
        if value equals target {
            increment count
        }
        if value is smaller than target {
            uniqueCombinations(set, target - value, value)
        }
    }
}

uniqueCombinations([1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200], 200, 200)
```

Alternatively, you can create a copy of the set before every recursion, and remove the elements from it that you don't want repeated.

The rising/falling sequence method also works with iterations. Let's say you want to find all unique combinations of three letters. This algorithm will print results like `a,c,e`, but not `a,e,c` or `e,a,c`:

```
for letter1 is 'a' to 'x' {
    for letter2 is first letter after letter1 to 'y' {
        for letter3 is first letter after letter2 to 'z' {
            print [letter1,letter2,letter3]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'll pay forward a kindness that a mentor and friend paid me long ago. There is no such word as recurse.  It's recur!  Ironically, my friend is not a native English speaker...

Comment: @Gene Thanks. Apparently "recurse" is now an accepted verb, although "recursion" and "recursive" were indeed in use earlier; http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recurse

Comment: Okay. It still sounds to me like someone someone has placed a hex on something twice... I guess next week police will be apprehensing criminals.  .. ;-)

Comment: @Gene I blame management consultants and their incentivizationalism.

Answer (score 3):

m69 gives a nice strategy that often works, but I think it's worthwhile to better understand *why* it works.  When trying to count items (of any kind), the general principle is:

**Think of a rule that classifies *any given item* into *exactly one* of several non-overlapping categories.**  That is, come up with a list of concrete categories A, B, ..., Z that will make the following sentence true: *An item is either in category A, or in category B, or ..., or in category Z*.

Once you have done this, you can safely count the number of items in each category and add these counts together, comfortable in the knowledge that (a) any item that is counted in one category is not counted again in any other category, and (b) any item that you want to count is in *some* category (i.e., none are missed).

How could we form categories for your specific problem here?  One way to do it is to notice that every item (i.e., every multiset of coin values that sums to the desired total N) either contains the 50-coin exactly zero times, or it contains it exactly once, or it contains it exactly twice, or ..., or it contains it exactly RoundDown(N / 50) times.  These categories don't overlap: if a solution uses exactly 5 50-coins, it pretty clearly can't also use exactly 7 50-coins, for example.  Also, every solution is clearly in some category (notice that we include a category for the case in which no 50-coins are used).  So if we had a way to count, for any given k, the number of solutions that use coins from the set {1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200} to produce a sum of N *and use exactly k 50-coins*, then we could sum over all k from 0 to N/50 and get an accurate count.

How to do this efficiently?  This is where the recursion comes in.  The number of solutions that use coins from the set {1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200} to produce a sum of N and use exactly k 50-coins is equal to the number of solutions that sum to N-50k *and do not use any 50-coins*, i.e. use coins only from the set {1,2,5,10,20,100,200}.  This of course works for any particular coin denomination that we could have chosen, so these subproblems have the same shape as the original problem: we can solve each one by simply choosing another coin arbitrarily (e.g. the 10-coin), forming a new set of categories based on this new coin, counting the number of items in each category and summing them up.  The subproblems become smaller until we reach some simple base case that we process directly (e.g. no allowed coins left: then there is 1 item if N=0, and 0 items otherwise).

I started with the 50-coin (instead of, say, the largest or the smallest coin) to emphasise that the particular choice used to form the set of non-overlapping categories doesn't matter for the correctness of the algorithm.  But in practice, passing explicit representations of sets of coins around is unnecessarily expensive.  Since we don't actually care about the particular sequence of coins to use for forming categories, we're free to choose a more efficient representation.  Here (and in many problems), it's convenient to represent the set of allowed coins *implicitly* as simply a single integer, maxCoin, which we interpret to mean that the first maxCoin coins in the original ordered list of coins are the allowed ones.  This limits the possible sets we can represent, but here that's OK: If we always choose the last allowed coin to form categories on, we can communicate the new, more-restricted "set" of allowed coins to subproblems very succinctly by simply passing the argument maxCoin-1 to it.  This is the essence of m69's answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding this explanation; it may indeed not be immediately clear to everyone why rising/falling sequences work. I've answered several permutation questions lately, and after a while it becomes the obvious go-to strategy.

Answer (score 0):

There's some good guidance here. Another way to think about this is as a dynamic program. For this, we must pose the problem as a simple decision among options that leaves us with a smaller version of the same problem. It boils out to a certain kind of recursive expression.

Put the coin values c0, c1, ... c_(n-1) in any order you like.  Then define W(i,v) as the number of ways you can make change for value v using coins ci, c_(i+1), ... c_(n-1). The answer we want is W(0,200).  All that's left is to define W:

```
W(i,v) = sum_[k = 0..floor(200/ci)]  W(i+1, v-ci*k)
```

In words: the number of ways we can make change with coins ci onward is to sum up all the ways we can make change after a decision to use some feasible number k of coins ci, removing that much value from the problem.

Of course we need base cases for the recursion. This happens when i=n-1: the last coin value. At this point there's a way to make change if and only if the value we need is an exact multiple of c_(n-1).

```
W(n-1,v) = 1 if v % c_(n-1) == 0 and 0 otherwise.
```

We generally don't want to implement this as a simple recursive function. The same argument values occur repeatedly, which leads to an exponential (in n and v) amount of wasted computation. There are simple ways to avoid this. Tabular evaluation and memoization are two.

Another point is that it *is* more efficient to have the values in descending order. By taking big chunks of value early, the total number of recursive evaluations is minimized. Additionally, since c_(n-1) is now 1, the base case is just W(n-1)=1. Now it becomes fairly obvious that we can add a second base case as an optimization: `W(n-2,v) = floor(v/c_(n-2))`. That's how many times the `for` loop will sum W(n-1,1) = 1!

But this is gilding a lilly. The problem is so small that exponential behavior doesn't signify. Here is a little implementation to show that order really doesn't matter:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define n 8
int cv[][n] = {
  {200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1},
  {1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200},
  {1,10,100,2,20,200,5,50},
};
int *c;

int w(int i, int v) {
  if (i == n - 1) return v % c[n - 1] == 0;
  int sum = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k <= v / c[i]; ++k)
    sum += w(i + 1, v - c[i] * k);
  return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  unsigned p;
  if (argc != 2 || sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &p) != 1 || p > 2) p = 0;
  c = cv[p];
  printf("Ways(%u) = %d\n", p, w(0, 200));
  return 0;
}
```

Drumroll, please...

```
$ ./foo 0
Ways(0) = 73682
$ ./foo 1
Ways(1) = 73682
$ ./foo 2 
Ways(2) = 73682
```